# How to parse tab-delimited text file with 4th column as json and remove certain keys?

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing, text

I have a text file that is 26 Gb, The line format is as follow

`/type/edition  /books/OL10000135M  4   2010-04-24T17:54:01.503315  {"publishers": ["Bernan Press"], "physical_format": "Hardcover", "subtitle": "9th November - 3rd December, 1992", "key": "/books/OL10000135M", "title": "Parliamentary Debates, House of Lords, Bound Volumes, 1992-93", "identifiers": {"goodreads": ["6850240"]}, "isbn_13": ["9780107805401"], "languages": [{"key": "/languages/eng"}], "number_of_pages": 64, "isbn_10": ["0107805405"], "publish_date": "December 1993", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2010-04-24T17:54:01.503315"}, "authors": [{"key": "/authors/OL2645777A"}], "latest_revision": 4, "works": [{"key": "/works/OL7925046W"}], "type": {"key": "/type/edition"}, "subjects": ["Government - Comparative", "Politics / Current Events"], "revision": 4}`

I'm trying to get only the last columns which is a json and from that Json I'm only trying to save the "title", "isbn 13", "isbn 10"

I was able to save only the last column with this code

```
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
# File names: to read in from and read out to
input_file = '../inputFile/ol_dump_editions_2019-10-31.txt'
output_file = '../outputFile/output.txt'

## ==================== ##
##  Using module 'csv'  ##
## ==================== ##
with open(input_file) as to_read:
    with open(output_file, "w") as tmp_file:
        reader = csv.reader(to_read, delimiter = "\t")
        writer = csv.writer(tmp_file)

        desired_column = [4]        # text column

        for row in reader:     # read one row at a time
            myColumn = list(row[i] for i in desired_column)   # build the output row (process)
            writer.writerow(myColumn) # write it
```

but this doesn't return a proper json object instead returns everything with a double quotations next to it. Also how would I extract certain values from the json as a new json

EDIT:

`"{""publishers"": [""Bernan Press""], ""physical_format"": ""Hardcover"", ""subtitle"": ""9th November - 3rd December, 1992"", ""key"": ""/books/OL10000135M"", ""title"": ""Parliamentary Debates, House of Lords, Bound Volumes, 1992-93"", ""identifiers"": {""goodreads"": [""6850240""]}, ""isbn_13"": [""9780107805401""], ""languages"": [{""key"": ""/languages/eng""}], ""number_of_pages"": 64, ""isbn_10"": [""0107805405""], ""publish_date"": ""December 1993"", ""last_modified"": {""type"": ""/type/datetime"", ""value"": ""2010-04-24T17:54:01.503315""}, ""authors"": [{""key"": ""/authors/OL2645777A""}], ""latest_revision"": 4, ""works"": [{""key"": ""/works/OL7925046W""}], ""type"": {""key"": ""/type/edition""}, ""subjects"": [""Government - Comparative"", ""Politics / Current Events""], ""revision"": 4}"`

EDIT 2:

so im trying to read this file which is a tab separated file with the following columns:

type - type of record (/type/edition, /type/work etc.)
key - unique key of the record. (/books/OL1M etc.)
revision - revision number of the record
last_modified - last modified timestamp
JSON - the complete record in JSON format

Im trying to read the JSON file and from that Json im only trying to get the "title", "isbn 13", "isbn 10" as a json and save it to the file as a row

so every row should look like the original but with only those key and values

Comment: Please share what your code returns.

Comment: sorry I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straight-forward way of doing it. You would need to repeat this and extract the desired data from each line of the file as it's being read, line-by-line (the default way text file reading is handled in Python).

```
import json

line = '/type/edition   /books/OL10000135M  4   2010-04-24T17:54:01.503315  {"publishers": ["Bernan Press"], "physical_format": "Hardcover", "subtitle": "9th November - 3rd December, 1992", "key": "/books/OL10000135M", "title": "Parliamentary Debates, House of Lords, Bound Volumes, 1992-93", "identifiers": {"goodreads": ["6850240"]}, "isbn_13": ["9780107805401"], "languages": [{"key": "/languages/eng"}], "number_of_pages": 64, "isbn_10": ["0107805405"], "publish_date": "December 1993", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2010-04-24T17:54:01.503315"}, "authors": [{"key": "/authors/OL2645777A"}], "latest_revision": 4, "works": [{"key": "/works/OL7925046W"}], "type": {"key": "/type/edition"}, "subjects": ["Government - Comparative", "Politics / Current Events"], "revision": 4}'

csv_cols = line.split('\t')
json_data = json.loads(csv_cols[4])
#print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))

desired = {key: json_data[key] for key in ("title", "isbn_13", "isbn_10")}
result = json.dumps(desired, indent=4)
print(result)
```

Output from sample line:

```
{
    "title": "Parliamentary Debates, House of Lords, Bound Volumes, 1992-93",
    "isbn_13": [
        "9780107805401"
    ],
    "isbn_10": [
        "0107805405"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but im trying to keep its json with key and value

Comment: yes but the problem is when writing it. It doesn't write to the file correctly `{,"""",p,u,b,l,i,s,h,e,r,s,"""",:, ,[,"""",B,e,r,n,a,n, ,P,r,e,s,s,"""",],",", ,"""",p,h,y,s,i,c,a,l,_,f,o,r,m,a,t,"""",:, ,"""",H,a,r,d,c,o,v,e,r,"""",",", ,"""",s,u,b,t,i,t,l,e,"""",:, ,"""",9,t,h, ,N,o,v,e,m,b,e,r, ,-, ,3,r,d, ,D,e,c,e,m,b,e,r,",", ,1,9,9,2,"""",",",t,a,r,y, ,D,e,b,a,t,e,s,",", ,H,o,u,s,e, ,o,f, ,L,o,r,d,s,",", ,B,o,u,n,d, ,V,o,l,u,m,e,s,",", ,1,9,9,2,-,9,3,"""",",", ,"""",i,d,e,n,t,i,f,i,e,d,a,t,e,"""",:, ,"""",D,e,c,e,m,b,e,r, }`

Comment: Then you must not being doing it correctly. To write the result to a file, use something like: `outfile.write(result + '\n')`.

Answer (score 1):

So given that your current code returns the following:

```
result = '{""publishers"": [""Bernan Press""], ""physical_format"": ""Hardcover"", ""subtitle"": ""9th November - 3rd December, 1992"", ""key"": ""/books/OL10000135M"", ""title"": ""Parliamentary Debates, House of Lords, Bound Volumes, 1992-93"", ""identifiers"": {""goodreads"": [""6850240""]}, ""isbn_13"": [""9780107805401""], ""languages"": [{""key"": ""/languages/eng""}], ""number_of_pages"": 64, ""isbn_10"": [""0107805405""], ""publish_date"": ""December 1993"", ""last_modified"": {""type"": ""/type/datetime"", ""value"": ""2010-04-24T17:54:01.503315""}, ""authors"": [{""key"": ""/authors/OL2645777A""}], ""latest_revision"": 4, ""works"": [{""key"": ""/works/OL7925046W""}], ""type"": {""key"": ""/type/edition""}, ""subjects"": [""Government - Comparative"", ""Politics / Current Events""], ""revision"": 4}'
```

Looks like what you need to do is: First - Replace those double-double-quotes with regular double quotes, otherwise things are not parsible:

```
res = result.replace('""','"')
```

Now `res` is convertible to a JSON object:

```
import json
my_json = json.loads(res)
```

`my_json` now looks like this:

```
{'authors': [{'key': '/authors/OL2645777A'}],
 'identifiers': {'goodreads': ['6850240']},
 'isbn_10': ['0107805405'],
 'isbn_13': ['9780107805401'],
 'key': '/books/OL10000135M',
 'languages': [{'key': '/languages/eng'}],
 'last_modified': {'type': '/type/datetime',
  'value': '2010-04-24T17:54:01.503315'},
 'latest_revision': 4,
 'number_of_pages': 64,
 'physical_format': 'Hardcover',
 'publish_date': 'December 1993',
 'publishers': ['Bernan Press'],
 'revision': 4,
 'subjects': ['Government - Comparative', 'Politics / Current Events'],
 'subtitle': '9th November - 3rd December, 1992',
 'title': 'Parliamentary Debates, House of Lords, Bound Volumes, 1992-93',
 'type': {'key': '/type/edition'},
 'works': [{'key': '/works/OL7925046W'}]}
```

You can conveniently get any field you want from this object:

```
my_json['title']
# 'Parliamentary Debates, House of Lords, Bound Volumes, 1992-93'
my_json['isbn_10'][0]
# '0107805405'
```

Comment: Do I need to parse using pandas like the answer below says or and is my way pulling everything into ram ? beause I thought it was only reading and writing rows one at a time

Comment: You can definitely use Pandas too, great tool. I always prefer doing this kind of complex parsing operations with packages like csv and json and get as flexible as I want with explicit loops and conditions. Pandas functions can get you to the same result with slightly more magical functions, which may have a learning curve.

Comment: and doing `myColumn = list(row[i] for i in desired_column)   # build the output row (process)
            res = myColumn.replace('""','"')
            writer.writerow(res) # write it` returns an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: Let's go step by step. Does `myColumn.replace('""','"')` produce an error?

Comment: Yes line 21 which is that line gives an error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Then myColumn is not what you shared, but instead has brackets. So please try: `myColumn[0].replace('""','"')`

Comment: Doing that gives this result `{,"""",p,u,b,l,i,s,h,e,r,s,"""",:, ,[,"""",B,e,r,n,a,n, ,P,r,e,s,s,"""",],",", ,"""",p,h,y,s,i,c,a,l,_,f,o,r,m,a,t,"""",:, ,"""",H,a,r,d,c,o,v,e,r,"""",",", ,"""",s,u,b,t,i,t,l,e,"""",:, ,"""",9,t,h, ,N,o,v,e,m,b,e,r, ,-, ,3,r,d, ,D,e,c,e,m,b,e,r,",", ,1,9,9,2,"""",",",t,a,r,y, ,D,e,b,a,t,e,s,",", ,H,o,u,s,e, ,o,f, ,L,o,r,d,s,",", ,B,o,u,n,d, ,V,o,l,u,m,e,s,",", ,1,9,9,2,-,9,3,"""",",", ,"""",i,d,e,n,t,i,f,i,e,d,a,t,e,"""",:, ,"""",D,e,c,e,m,b,e,r, }`

Comment: ok I see that when I print column[0] it does print the right thing but the problem occurs when I write it

Comment: @j.doe So does `my_json` give you exactly the same thing my answer has? If it does, we can fix the `write` part.

Comment: yes but I want to write the original row with those keys as json `{
    "title": "Parliamentary Debates, House of Lords, Bound Volumes, 1992-93",
    "isbn_13": [
        "9780107805401"
    ],
    "isbn_10": [
        "0107805405"
    ]
}
 `like this

Comment: Yeh the problem is that its not writing the json to the file right

Comment: @j.doe To prevent any convolution, please post that as a separate question. It is very hard to understand what you'd like to write to the file and how. You may want to start a clean discussion for it. Regarding the current question: Please consider marking the most helpful answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Especially because your example is so large, I'd recommend using a specialized library such as [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), which has a `read_csv` method, or even [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html), which supports out-of-memory operations.

Both of these systems will automatically parse out the quotations for you, and dask will do so in "pieces" direct from disk so you never have to try to load 26GB into RAM.

In both libraries, you can then access the columns you want like this:

```py
data = read_csv(PATH)
data["ColumnName"]
```

You can then parse these rows either using `json.loads()` (`import json`) or you can use the pandas/dask json implementations. If you can give some more details of what you're expecting, I can help you draft a more specific code example.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I added a second edit which explains the problem better, I'm very new to this data world any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is it possible to use chunks in pandas to do this instead of dask as im familiar with pandas

Answer (score 0):

I saved your data to a file to see if i could read just the rows, let me know if this works:

```
lines = zzread.split('\n')  
temp=[] 
for to_read in lines: 
    if len(to_read) == 0:  
        break  
    new_to_read = '{' + to_read.split('{',1)[1] 
    temp.append(json.loads(new_to_read)) 
for row in temp: 
      print(row['isbn_13'])
```

If that works this should create a json for you:

```
lines = zzread.split('\n')  
temp=[] 
for to_read in lines: 
    if len(to_read) == 0:  
        break  
    new_to_read = '{' + to_read.split('{',1)[1] 
    temp.append(json.loads(new_to_read)) 
new_json=[]
for row in temp: 
    new_json.append({'title': row['title'], 'isbn_13': row['isbn_13'], 'isbn_10': row['isbn_10']})
```